# How do I use local MultiversX docker container node for local smart-contract development?

Tags: docker, smartcontracts, multiversx

I am new to MultiversX. I (think) successfully have local node running in docker?

Both of these yield same log output in portainer:

```
sudo docker run -d \
 --name my-elrond-testnet \
 -v ${PATH_TO_BLS_KEY_FILE}:/data/ \
 elrondnetwork/elrond-go-node:latest \
 --nodes-setup-file="/data/nodesSetup.json" \
 --p2p-config="/data/config/p2p.toml" \
 --validator-key-pem-file="/data/keys/validatorKey.pem"


sudo docker run -d \
  --name my-other-elrond-testnet \
  --mount type=bind,source=${PATH_TO_BLS_KEY_FILE}/,destination=/data \
  elrondnetwork/elrond-go-node:latest \
 --validator-key-pem-file="/data/validatorKey.pem"
```

But now I don't know what to do. How do I connect to that local node?

I wanted to use it as a local development node - I want to deploy smart contracts on it.

I have some experience with Solana and with NEAR.

I don't see that the container exposes any ports.

Do I need a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't docker but it successfully runs a local node(s).

https://docs.elrond.com/developers/setup-local-testnet/

I followed most of the instructions without an issue except that when I tried to run "erdpy" it failed.

But elsewhere I found " pip install erdpy"

Once you get erdpy working, the rest of the instructions went well, as far as getting a local node(s) to run.

I dont know yet about actually deploying a contract on it.

There's also this: https://docs.elrond.com/developers/setup-local-testnet-advanced/